# What this mysql instance storing on RAM memory apart from Innodb buffer pool: Linux - Mysql 5.6.2 High memory usage

Tags: mysql-5.6, memory

We have a mysql 5.6.2 installed on one of our clients machines.

```
Innodb buffer pool   : 3 GB
Max connections is   : 200
Max used connections : 100
Performace schema    : Enabled
Load                 : READ Intensive 
Data                 : Mostly Innodb
Key buffers and additional buffer pool are nominal.
In memory limit for temp table is 1 GB (`tmp_table` & `max_heap_table`).
```

We have observed it has occupied around **15GB resident memory on RAM**, which seems surprising.

```
This is when we read from a view with multiple simultaneous connections.     
When I checked in smaps for this process, I could see 3 GB innodb buffer 
pool size and along with that there are 160 memory maps each of 60 MB ( ~ 9 GB of RAM).
```

Can someone please explain what these memory maps could be?